# Error WrongProposalWeight when proposing a runtime upgrade using the council

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade, council

When trying to propose a `system.setCode` motion the extrinsic fails with `WrongProposalWeight`. We are experiencing this issue only with the above extrinsic and on polkadot-0.9.42 version.

On an earlier version of polkadot (0.9.36) it seems to work flawlessly!

I think something changed between 0.9.36 and 0.9.42 which impacts weight calculation regarding system extrinsics?

Edit: I found https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13771 which is causing the issue I think

Comment: What is your `MaxProposalWeight` set at ?

Comment: We have set it to 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weigh of `set_code` was not properly benchmarked until [this MR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13373), so it was probably assuming way too much weight. The proper way would be to integrate that into your runtime and then use the updated weights.
And additionally set your `MaxProposalWeight` to something sensible.

Another (hackier) way is to wrap the `System::set_code` in a `Utility::with_weight` call if you want to ignore the weight check. Note that this introduces the possibility of creating an overweight block, if the `set_code` does use more than the block limit. But so far the results for `set_code` indicated about 60ms, which should have more than enough room to not produce an overweight block.

Comment: The second solution does not work because the `Utility::with_weight` requires a root origin and the collective pallet does not provide that.

There is a third option that we actually went for. We created our own pallet to dispatch runtime upgrades, this call can only be called by the Council origin. You can check the weight for this call here: https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/45d9c139db1a9e6fb0d09613c2cd3ac03087ac0a/substrate-node/pallets/pallet-runtime-upgrade/src/lib.rs#L25

Comment: Wait, `set_code` also needs root. So how can you dispatch `set_code` but not `with_weight`?

Comment: We created our own pallet to dispatch `set_code` having configured some origin, see: https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/development/substrate-node/pallets/pallet-runtime-upgrade/src/lib.rs

Comment: Okay I dont understand the Question. Originally it was about `System::set_code`, but now you have your own pallet and use weight `T::BlockWeights::get().base_block`. So so can just benchmark it properly or reduce the weight if you are sure about it?